# External Javascript not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, dom-events

**This is the original codepen and on Firefox, keeps not working to me:** https://codepen.io/eddyerburgh/pen/zvdgpe

This simple external Javascript to toggle FAQS is not working on Firefox :

```
// Get all .faq-question
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-question");

// Assign openQuestion on click
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    questions[i].onclick = openQuestion;
}

// Apply .hidden to sibling .faq-answer
// Apply .open to .faq-question
function openQuestion(e) {
    var answer = (event.target).parentNode.getElementsByClassName("faq-answer")[0];
    if (-1 !== answer.className.indexOf("hidden")) {
        answer.className = answer.className.replace(" hidden", "");
    } else {
        answer.className += " hidden";
    }
    if (-1 !== event.target.className.indexOf("open")) {
        event.target.className = event.target.className.replace( " open", "");
    } else {
        event.target.className += " open";
    }
}
```

On Chrome and IE it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Could this be a problem with this part of the code:

```
// Get all .faq-question
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-question");

// Assign openQuestion on click
for ( var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++ ) {

  questions[i].onclick = openQuestion;

}
```

When I check the events it doesn't show this part.

Comment: Check your console by pressing F12. Do you see errors? Security warnings? Look at the Network tab. Is this file being loaded?

Comment: `is not working on Firefox` - can you expand on this? What should happen? What happens instead? Don't expect us to be able to "see" the problem as we only have your code fragment to work with

Comment: Also, I would learn to use [element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) - there's a "SHIM" for browsers that don't support it, in other words for IE9 or earlier

Comment: Let's see the include to this javascript page in the main html file, maybe it's not linking to the external javascript page correctly.

Comment: @KolobCanyon - specifically where the file is included in relation to the elements with class `faq-question`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.xx.com/theme/js/faqscript.js"></script>
Inserted it in the body at the bottom.. the in firefox f12 the script is loaded...

Comment: @Nefb Use backticks (`) to format code, [edit] the question to add substantial details.

Comment: @kolob i even added it to the header but still nothing.. the javascript is loaded but it doesnt do what is supposed to (faq toggle)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the console you will clearly see the error

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

You defined the event as `e`, but use `event`

```
function openQuestion(e) {  <-- use e
    var answer = (event.target)  <-- you use event
```

change it to be `event`

```
function openQuestion(event) {
```

Comment: so should i use event on both?